# Is it safe to use wood from a tree if it has a fungal infection?

Tags: trees, diseases, fungus

Some ash trees have been cut down near where I work. I was thinking about taking some of the log sections for woodworking material, but I heard something suggesting that these trees might be getting removed because of sooty canker disease. If these trees are in fact infected, does handling and using the wood from them risk spreading the fungus (for example to trees in my yard at home), and is there any health risk to me and other people?

Answer (score 1):

If a tree was cut down to prevent the spread of an infections disease and/or invasive pest, then you shouldn't relocate the wood to a location that doesn't already have that disease or pest. In general, wood from an infested tree can spread the infestation to uninfested trees. Since you aren't sure what disease those trees had, you have no way to check whether the trees around your home already have that disease or pest. For now, leave the wood where it is.

If you can find out for certain why those trees were cut down, then you can make a reasonable risk assessment. Start by looking up information on the *specific* disease or pest. Find out what range it has, and whether it's currently widespread in your area. Your government should have an agency that provides information about specific tree pests, and advice about whether you should use and transport wood from infested trees. Some invasive species actually have quarantine zones, and there are laws prohibiting the transportation of infested material outside the quarantine zone. In the US, the best information about tree diseases and pests is provided by state-level departments of agriculture. The USDA also provides some information.

Comment: To clarify, I live just a few miles from where I work (same city), so I wouldn't be moving the wood very far. But I'm leaning toward leaving it alone just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Don't move the wood!

We don't have any ash trees within 50 miles of where I live and the same is true for much of the east coast of North America and Europe.  This is due to the [Emerald ash borer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_ash_borer) whose larvae eat the tissue under the bark.

This insect has spread widely and caused the death of [millions of ash trees at a cost in the billions of dollars](https://www.invasivespeciescentre.ca/invasive-species/meet-the-species/invasive-insects/emerald-ash-borer/).  Your local civic/state/provincial/county authorities should have published advice not to move wood as the larvae can be inside.  They are so destructive they don't need any assistance from us in spreading.